# Проверка сайта на работоспособность

Tags: веб-программирование, хостинг

Итак, сайт создан. (ie при этом вынес все остатки мозга). Что мне с ним делать? Существуют бесплатные хостинги, то там кагбэ доменное имя платное. Вроде бы есть narod.ru, но там кагбэ мой логин и будет являться доменным именем. Короче, что делать? Куда залить сайт?

Comment: залейте на нормальный платный хостинг. не вижу проблемы.

Comment: Сайт не несет вообще никакой смысловой нагрузки. Получилось довольно-таки неплохо, но это был кагбэ учебный проект - ифреймы, подзагрузка страниц,игра с классам и т.д. Деньги за хост платить вообще не вижу смысла.

Comment: ну тогда проверяйте на бесплатном хостинге... доменное ru/рф имя стоит от 90 рублей в год. не хотите платить? пользуйтесь тем, что есть) от нас-то вы что хотите? :) дать домен погонять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Регистрируем доменное имя
2. Выбираем и заказываем хостинг
3. Делаем с этим что хотим (и что позволяет хостинг)

P.S. Пункты 1 и 2 можно творчески варьировать.

P.P.S. Если хочется Очень Много Геморроя - нужно иметь дело с бесплатными хостингами, бесплатными доменными именами и прочей халявой.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрите мой предыдущий комментарий

Comment: @Deus, перечитайте P.P.S. :-) При такой постановке я вообще не вижу смысла задавать здесь подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

из бесплатных мне понравился 16mb.com

Comment: Собсно: http://www.freewebspace.net/free/AdvSearch